# Why do my move methods not work?

Tags: python, pygame

When I run the following code, I get this error

```
reindeer.moveUp(screen)

File "C:\Users\adity\Desktop\Python\CPT.py", line 38, in moveUp

self.y = self.y - 3
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'y'
```

I want to move the rectangle up or down every time the user presses w or s using methods in the reindeer class. Is it because of something wrong with the methods?

Why does the program not know what y is? I assigned it in the list of attributes for the class.

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (1000, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill(WHITE)
class Reindeer():
    def __init__(self): 
        self.color = (255,0,0)
        self.y_move = 3
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100
        self.width = 100
        self.length = 100
    def draw(screen, self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [self.x,self.y,self.width,self.length], 0)
    def moveDown(screen, self):
        self.y = self.y + 3
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x,self.y,self.width, self.length], 0)
    def moveUp(screen, self):
        self.y = self.y - 3
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x,self.y,self.width,self.length], 0)
reindeer = Reindeer()
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                reindeer.moveDown(screen)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                reindeer.moveUp(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()


    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  This code is hardly minimal, and fails to run for lack of `moon.png`.

Comment: When I comment out that line, and the other two that reference `image1`, I get no error; the game hangs with a white screen.

Comment: You have reversed `self` and `screen` in your method definitions. `self` always comes first. Thus, what you are trying to use as `self` (the `Reindeer` object) is actually the `pygame.Surface` object, and vice versa. *As the error message says,* the `Surface` object does not have a `y` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally dug down to it, by (sigh) reading the code.  You have your method parameters in the wrong order: the first parameter is, by definition, the invoking object.  Switch your method signatures:

```
def moveDown(self, screen):
```

... and the same for all others.